# Do $p,q$ exist such $|p-q|+|a_{p}-a_{q}|=2014$

Tags: number-theory, contest-math

> Let $\{a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_{2016}\}=\{1,2,3,\ldots,2016\}=A$ be such
>   $$\dfrac{a_i-a_j}{i-j}\neq 1,\forall i,j\in A\text{ with } i\neq j.$$
>   Show that there exists $p,q\in A$ such that
>   $$|p-q|+|a_p-a_q|=2014.$$

My approach is the following:

Put $x_i=a_i-i$, then we have $$\sum_{i=1}^{2016} x_i=\sum_{i=1}^{2016} a_i-\sum_{i=1}^{2016} i=0,|x_j|\le 2016,j=1,2,\cdots,2016$$
and
$$\dfrac{a_i-a_j}{i-j}\neq 1,\Longleftrightarrow x_i\neq x_j\forall i,j\in A\text{ with }i\neq j$$I'm stuck here and I don't know how to proceed.  Thanks.

Comment: You can use the pigeonhole principle to conclude that there are $x_p$ and $x_q$ with $p\neq q$ and $x_p = x_q \pmod{2014}$. I wrote an incorrect solution but decided to delete it since there are two many problems. 1) $x_p - x_q = \pm 2014$ does not lead to the desired equality, 2) $x_p - x_q = \pm 4028$ is also possible, which leads nowhere.

Comment: Thank you,so I think this problem is interesting,I think this right constan $2014$ can change any other postive intergers,

Comment: Some numeric results: If we generalize this to permutations of $[1,n]$ with $a_i-a_j\ne i-j$ and look for $|p-q|+|a_p-a_q|=n-2$, there are $2,0,2,10$ permutations without such $p$, $q$ for $n=4,6,8,10$, respectively; so the solution may have to make use of some specific features of $2016$, perhaps being divisible by $3$.

Comment: Here are the solutions without such $p$, $q$ for $n=4,8,10$ -- perhaps they contain a clue to a proof: $n = 4$:
[2, 4, 1, 3]
[3, 1, 4, 2];
$n = 8$:
[4, 8, 2, 6, 3, 7, 1, 5]
[7, 3, 5, 1, 8, 4, 6, 2];
$n = 10$:
[2, 6, 9, 4, 7, 1, 10, 5, 8, 3]
[4, 8, 2, 6, 9, 3, 7, 1, 10, 5]
[5, 10, 8, 2, 4, 7, 9, 3, 1, 6]
[5, 10, 9, 3, 8, 7, 4, 2, 1, 6]
[5, 10, 9, 7, 4, 3, 8, 2, 1, 6]
[6, 1, 10, 4, 8, 2, 5, 9, 3, 7]
[8, 3, 6, 1, 10, 4, 7, 2, 5, 9]
[9, 4, 8, 5, 1, 10, 6, 3, 7, 2]
[9, 8, 4, 7, 1, 10, 6, 5, 3, 2]
[9, 8, 6, 5, 1, 10, 4, 7, 3, 2]

Comment: @san: I'm afraid I don't see the problem. What rule does that violate?

Comment: @joriki no rule is violated. I really misunderstood the problem.

Comment: Do you prove the existence of $p$ and $q$ for all possible permutation maps satisfying $\frac{a_{i}-a_{j}}{i-j} \neq 1, \forall i,j \in A$ with $i \neq j$ or do you only need to show the existence of one such permutation map and then show the existence of $p$ and $q$ (say via positive example)?

Comment: For 2015 instead of 2014 the methods that were suggested seem to work fine, I hope there's no mistake in the statement of the problem.

Comment: @ChristianRemling, no mistake, I think. Inspired by joriki's findings, I tried to make induction with step $3$. It seems to work, but a horrible lot of writing...

Comment: WAIT: It seems too easy. If p and q are 1008 and 1, it becomes 1007 + 1007 = 2014! There is no point in answering ... ? Am I misunderstanding?

Comment: @PythonGuy: Probably. :-)  The problem situation is this.  The sequence $a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_{2016}$ contains each integer from $1$ through $2016$ in some order, such that for any $i \not= j$, $a_j-a_i \not= j-i$.  Your observation doesn't form a counterexample because although $|p-q| = 1007$, it is not the case that $|a_p-a_q| = 1007$ for any conceivable sequence $a_i$.

Comment: @zhoraster Actually, there are solutions for $n=12, 18, 24$.  In fact after computing up to $30$ or so, there was only even value of $n$ for which the generalized statement is true, and that was $n=6$ as identified by joriki.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is false as stated.  Here is a counterexample that works for any $n=4k$:

$$\vec a = (\color{red}{4k-1}, \color{blue}{2k-1}, \color{red}{4k-3}, \color{blue}{2k-3}, \ldots, \color{red}{2k+3}, \color{blue}{3}, \color{red}{2k+1}, \color{blue}{1}; \color{green}{4k}, \color{brown}{2k}, \color{green}{4k-2}, \color{brown}{2k-2}, \ldots, \color{green}{2k+2}, \color{brown}{2}).$$

In formulaic terms this is:
$$a_i = \begin{cases}
\color{red}{4k-i},& \text{if $i\le2k$ and $i$ is odd};\\
\color{blue}{2k+1-i},& \text{if $i\le2k$ and $i$ is even};\\
\color{green}{6k+1-i},& \text{if $i>2k$ and $i$ is odd};\\
\color{brown}{4k+2-i},& \text{if $i>2k$ and $i$ is even}.
\end{cases}$$

I leave it as an exercise to verify this is a permutation (notice that all the odd values of $a$ occur in the first half, and all the even values occur in the second).

We next verify that $\vec a$ satisfies the slope condition.  Clearly the values of $a_i-i$ are distinct within each clause, since locally $a_i$ is a line of slope $-1$, not $+1$.  But the following chart shows why no distinct clauses can overlap:

$$\text{$a_i-i$ is } \begin{cases}
\text{even and $>0$},& \text{if $i\le2k$ and $i$ is odd};\\
\text{$\equiv 1 \pmod 4$},& \text{if $i\le2k$ and $i$ is even};\\
\text{$\equiv 3 \pmod 4$},& \text{if $i>2k$ and $i$ is odd};\\
\text{even and $<0$},& \text{if $i>2k$ and $i$ is even}.
\end{cases}.$$

Finally, it remains to show that $|p-q|+|a_p-a_q| \ne 4k-2$.  Again, within each clause this is trivial as $|p-q|+|a_p-a_q| = 2|p-q| < 4k$ if $p,q$ are from the same clause.

Suppose that $p,q$ are from different clauses (WLOG $p<q$) and that $|p-q|+|a_p-a_q| = 4k-2$.  Since $(p-q)-(a_p-a_q)$ is even, $a_p-p$ and $a_q-q$ *must* have the same parity.  Referring back to the previous chart, we see there are only two cases left to consider.

**Case 1.** $p\le 2k$, $p$ odd, $q>2k$, $q$ even.

Then $a_p = 4k-p > 2k \ge 4k+2-q = a_q$, so $|p-q|+|a_p-a_q| = (q-p) + (a_p-a_q) = 2(q-p-1) \equiv 0 \pmod 4$, which can't be $4k-2$.

**Case 2.** $p\le 2k$, $p$ even, $q>2k$, $q$ odd.

Then $a_p = 2k+1-p < 2k \le 6k+1-q = a_q$, so $|p-q|+|a_p-a_q| = (q-p) + (a_q-a_p) = 4k \ne 4k-2$.